# Viewing plesk site on local server

Tags: web, plesk, parallels

Whenever I try to go to the address of my website from the server that is hosted on (using Plesk) it just goes to the default plesk page.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed default index.html page from your account? Please remove that and upload your site index page.